# Is it possible to change URL of a pinned Web page in WP8?

Tags: 8.0, internet-explorer

I want to pin a page with a certain URL. Unfortunately, when I open it in IE, I get redirected to another page, and thus I can only pin it, not the original URL. Is it possible to pin the original URL somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I have found a way to be able to do what you need to do.

Note: I have tried this on Windows Phone 7 and it should work in Windows Phone 8 too.

Start by removing all internet connectivity from your phone i.e. put your phone in airplane mode (no data plan / wifi ).

Now, go to Internet Explorer and type in the URL you want to pin. Because you have no internet, the page will finish loading without doing a redirect. Now tape the `More...` and then `pin to start`.

Hope this helps :)

[Here are some of the other things you can pin](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/start/pin-things-to-start). Obviously the above technique isn't published on the Microsoft website!

---

**Late edit: an alternative (and prettier?) way to do this**

1. Download the [WizTiles app from the Windows Phone App Store](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/wiztiles/54397d90-7f29-46b3-81b9-f78c3fd3b779)
2. With this app (or other such apps), you can create your down tiles to do specific tasks- one such thing is to create a tile that goes to a specific web page.

Advantage of using this method over the method used above: you get to specify what your tile looks like as opposed to a fixed "Page cannot be displayed" tile.

Comment: Excellent, outside of the box thinking. I just verified that it works on Windows Phone 8.

Comment: Wow :) Now I hate myself for not thinking about it! :)

Comment: By the way, the tile now displays "Page not available" thumbnail. Maybe it is possible to force it to reload itself?

Comment: Clicking on the pinned tile when you have internet connectivity doesn't change the tile thumbnail?

Comment: Apparently, no. I clicked it, I let it load the page, then I close IE and the tile is the same

Comment: I guess that would be a drawback of the above technique then...

Comment: Ok, still better than being directed to the wrong page :)

Comment: I have found another way to do this too. Please see the edited answer

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to change the pinned tile. The best one can do is delete an existing tile and re-pin a new url.

You still cannot do what you request. You can only pin the url of that is in the address bar of the page as it is. If a site changes the address, than that is the url that will be pinned.